# C++ 2 Dimensional Vectors

Tags: c++

Im currently taking a C++ course and  I am learning about vectors. Below there is a code I wrote where I am assigning  values to different vectors. Everything runs fine until I get to the part where I must declare an empty 2 dimensional vector. Below instructions of the problem  plus code using XCode. ( I tried compiling through the terminal and it was the same outcome)

```
/* Section 7
 Challange

 Write a C++ program as follows:

 Declare 2 empty vectors of intergers named vector1 and vector2.


 Add 10 and 20 to vector1 dynamically using push_back
 Display the elements in vector1 using the at() method as well as its size
 using the size() method.

 Add 100 and 200 to vector2 dynamically using push_back
 Display the elements in vector2 using the at() method as well as its size
 using the size() method.

 Decalre an empty 2D vector called vector_2d
 TIP: A vector inside a vector.

 Add vector1 to vector_2d dynamically using push_back
 Add vector2 to vector_2d dynamically using push_back

 Display the elements in vector_2d using the at() method

 Change vector1.at(0) to 1000.

 Display the elements in vector_2d again using the at() method

 Display the elements in vector1
 */

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>



int main(){


    std::vector <int> vector1;
    std::vector <int> vector2;

    int vector1_1addition;
    int vector1_2addition;

    std::cin >> vector1_1addition; //add 10
    std::cin >> vector1_2addition; //add 20

    vector1.push_back (vector1_1addition);
    vector1.push_back (vector1_2addition);

    std::cout << "The numbers in vector 1 are: " << vector1.at(0) <<" " << vector1.at(1) <<std::endl;
    std::cout << "The size of the vector 1 is: " << vector1.size() << std::endl;

    int vector2_1addition;
    int vector2_2addition;

    std::cin >> vector2_1addition; //add 100
    std::cin >> vector2_2addition; //add 200

    vector2.push_back (vector2_1addition);
    vector2.push_back (vector2_2addition);

    std::cout << "The numbers in vector 2 are: " << vector2.at(0) << " " << vector2.at(1) <<std::endl;
    std::cout << "The size of vector 2 is: " << vector2.size() << std::endl;

    std::vector <std::vector <int> > vector_2d;

    std::cout << "The elements in the 2 dimensional vector are: " << &vector_2d.at(0) << &vector_2d.at(1) << std::endl;



    vector1.at(0) = 1000;

    std::cout << " The new elements in the 2 dimensional vector are: " << &vector_2d.at(0) << &vector_2d.at(1) << std::endl;


    std::cout << " The new elemenrs in vector 1 are: " << vector1.at(0) << vector1.at(1) << std::endl;



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's your question? This isn't a site to do or check your homework for you. That's what your instructors are for.

Comment: There's something missing from your question, namely an actual C++ question. "Everything runs fine until I get to the part where I must declare an empty 2 dimensional vector" is not a question.

Comment: You try to print something that doesn't exist; obviously you will get an error there. You need to actually ```push_back``` values into your 2D vector like the instructions say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is where you are printing the values of the 2 dimensional vector that don't yet exist, before you print them you need to declare them by using push_back to add the values to it.

Answer (score 0):

Great Udemy course!

1. `vector_2d.pushback(vector1);` and `vector_2d.pushback(vector2);` need to be added after the declaration of your vector_2d.
2. you also need to change:

   ```
   std::cout << "The elements in the 2 dimensional vector are: " << **&vector_2d.at(0)** 
   << **&vector_2d.at(1)** << std::endl;
   ```

   AND:

   ```
   std::cout << " The new elements in the 2 dimensional vector are: " << 
   **&vector_2d.at(0)** << **&vector_2d.at(1)** << std::endl;
   ```

   TO the below code pertaining to your output of a 2d vector:

   ```
   std::cout << "The elements in the 2 dimensional vector are: " << 
   &vector_2d.at(0).at(0) << &vector_2d.at(1).at(0) << std::endl;
   ```

   AND:

   ```
   std::cout << " The new elements in the 2 dimensional vector are: " << 
   &vector_2d.at(0) << &vector_2d.at(1) << std::endl;
   ```

Because the 2-d vector contains 2 rows and columns you need to output the `vector of vector of ints` as such.

Also, you need to add another output for the second row.

[Demo](https://ideone.com/cdrZdK)